# Best practice for handling android app user login/token?

Tags: android, authentication

So far I have a login page which posts to a web server which verifies the credentials and creates a token in the database which links to that user.

The token is then sent back to the app and stored in sharedpreferences.

What would the best way to verify this token? Should I verify this token every time an activity is created or resumed or simply verify it every time the app interacts with the server?

What I'm wanting is so that if the user was to change their password on the website or another device, it would log them out on the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I have done this is to check every time you interact with the server. This way, the user will think that it is just the action that is happening rather than potentially hindering on end-user performance.

If you wanted to check for a token change periodically, you could run a background task that checks the users credentials against those on the server. If all is well you can keep the current token and if not log them out with a message.

If you implement both, say on a timer of a minutes between automatic checks, and checked against the server with each interaction you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

After login i would pass the token on every call to the webserver. Let the webserver check if the token is valid and send back an appropriate response.  I also hope this can help - [json web token](http://jwt.io/)